# Display data in HTML form when loaded

Tags: javascript, html, forms

N00b alert; I know enough to be dangerous, so forgive my ignorance...I've been through all of the related questions here and elsewhere, but I just can't seem to comprehend the answer that's surely included in the responses :-(

I'm posting a record id to a page where I want a form to display with the contents of the related record. I'm getting the record in correctly (confirmed using the alert) with this script in the HEAD section (jquery 1.9 is called as well):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getSelectedCustomer () {        
    ...use the id to get the right record...
    databaseAPI.callback = function() {
        if (databaseAPI.error) {
            alert("Database Error: " + databaseAPI.error);
            } 
        else {
            var customerRecord = databaseAPI.result;
            alert("Test Callback: " + new String(customerRecord.full_name));
            $("#quoteForm").load(customerRecord);
            }
        return;
        };
    databaseAPI.ajaxGet();        
    }
window.onload = getSelectedCustomer; 
</script>
```

...and the form in the BODY to be loaded:

```
<form method="post" id="quoteForm" action="process_quote.php">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="<?php $customerRecord['full_name']; ?>" name="full_name"></td>
</tr>
...other bits of the form...
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

I know I'm incorrectly munging various things together. Can someone please get me straightened out on what to do?

Michael's answer solved the INPUT fields in the form. Didn't mention I had SELECT fields as well:

```
<select size="0" name="email_sent">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Changing INPUT to SELECT works.

Comment: What does `new String(customerRecord.full_name)` show in the alert?

Comment: It displays the correct name value included in the record. Michael's answer did the trick, but now I'm stuck on how to load the select fields (the input fields work perfectly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your missing is where code is being executed. The PHP code is being executed on the server, before being sent to the browser. The Javascript is then rendered by the browser. You can't pass variables back and forth between Javascript and PHP.

You want to inject the name with Javascript. I see you're already using jQuery, so the heavy lifting is already done for you. Remove the `value="<?php $customerRecord['full_name']; ?>"` from the PHP file, and replace `$("#quoteForm").load(customerRecord);` with `$("#quoteForm input[name='full_name']").val(customerRecord.full_name);`

Should work, might need some variation depending on your exact circumstances. At least it should put you down the right path.

Comment: w00t! w00t! Thank you so much. I knew it was something, ahem, wrong-headed about what was going on. This works perfectly for the input fields! Ummm, I tried to change 'input' to 'select' for the selects...need one more hint.

Comment: NVM; using SELECT for those field types DOES work. After tinkering I discovered I happened to have a DB issue with my first SELECT value being blank...Murphy...thank you again Michael; your answer solved my problem.